# Can ArgoCD manage applications in EKS clusters across different AWS accounts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, argocd, gitops

Can ArgoCD manage applications (via ApplicationSet) in EKS clusters across different AWS accounts? And is this a normal practice? (having different AWS accounts for test and prod environments)

Comment: Have you taken a look at this post? https://medium.com/@gustavo.zanotto/mastering-multi-cluster-kubernetes-management-on-aws-how-argocd-and-a-management-cluster-can-help-d43c2f44c640

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't. Declare the clusters in ArgoCD and that's it.